# Weird context menu behavior with multiple displays

Tags: gnome, display, appearance

The picture pretty much summarizes it:

[image: t]

Instead of popping up at the top panel, context menus appear where my main display's boundary is.

I'm under `Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS`

Comment: Same issue here, also on Gnome 3 and 18.04 LTS. My console's context menu is displayed at the edge of the screen; it also shows only one line and a scroll arrow instead of the whole menu.